# Evaluating weka classifier J48 with missing values in test set, R RWeka

Tags: r, weka, decision-tree

I have an error when evaluating a simple test set with evaluate_Weka_classifier. Trying to learn how the interface works from R to Weka with RWeka, but I still don't get this.

```
library("RWeka")
iris_input  <- iris[1:140,]
iris_test <- iris[-(1:140),]
iris_fit  <- J48(Species ~ ., data = iris_input)
evaluate_Weka_classifier(iris_fit, newdata = iris_test, numFolds=5)
```

No problems here, as we would assume (It is ofcourse a stupit test, no random holdout data etc). But now I want to simulate missing data (alot). So i set Petal.Width as missing:

```
iris_test$Petal.Width <- NA
evaluate_Weka_classifier(iris_fit, newdata = iris_test, numFolds=5)
```

Which gives the error: 
    Error in .jcall(evaluation, "S", "toSummaryString", complexity) : 
      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't have more folds than instances!

Edit: This error should tell me that I have not enough instances, but I have 10

Edit: If I use write.arff, it can be exported and read in by Weka. Change Petal.Width {} into Petal.Width numeric to make the two files exactly the same. Then it works in Weka.

Is this a thinking error? When reading Machine Learning, Practical machine learning tools and techniques it seems to be legit. Maybe I just have to tell RWeka that I want to use fractions when a split uses a missing variable?

Thnx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The issue is that you need to tell J48() what to do with missing values.**

```
library(RWeka)
?J48()  

#pertinent output  
J48(formula, data, subset, na.action,
control = Weka_control(), options = NULL)
```

na.action tells R what to do with missing values.  When following up on na.action you will find that "The ‘factory-fresh’ default is na.omit".  Under this setting of course there are not enough instances!

Instead of leaving na.action as the default omit, I have changed it as follows,

```
iris_fit<-J48(Species~., data = iris_input, na.action=NULL)
```

and it works like a charm!

Comment: Thank you. Again. I find it sometimes a bit hard to find all the options. I assumed it would be something like this :) So if i am correct, use na.action when building the model. After that, it is not needed when using evaluate?

Comment: I think you are right, you just have to tell the model what to do with missing values, and the evaluation takes it from there.  Sometimes I think it takes a second pair of eyes to find a problem. Even though the documentation for RWeka is not super complete (in my experience), its still a nice tool to have!